# Cocos2d with tabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

is it possible to integrate cocos2d with Normal iphone  or tabbarcontoller application?bcos I want to ingrate animation of cocos2d with tabbar application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible if you tweak a bit cocos2d in order it can manage several EAGLViews (so far there is only one eaglview).

[edit] Managing several opengl views is not the only method (it's case 4 in the doc below).

Flower Garden (appstore game) merges uikit and opengl layers (it's not made with cocos2d but it doesn't change anything to the problem, it's EAGLViews on top of UIKit). They've published an excellent presentation here :

http://gamesfromwithin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/GDC10_uikit_opengl.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple EAGLViews. You just need to add the UIToolbar as a subview of the openGLView of CCDirector. Then make sure your Cocos Layers have are vertical offset so they don't overlap.